# Bootstrap Columns not Responsive In Small Screen Size (Mobile)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a page which I'm building with bootstrap. the "Service" section displays correctly in lg and md size, but not in sm or xs (mobile) size. What am I missing here. I've tried including col-sm-12 and col-xs-12, but when I shrink the size of the screen to mobile device it does respond. Any help appreciated. If you want to take a look at the website live here's the link: http://pctechtips.org/apps/itcomp/

```
<div class="py-4 bg-light" id="prices">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="text-center">Service Prices</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="lead text-center">Bellow you can see a brief description of our services and price. These fall into three main category: Desktop Support, System Maintanance, and Network Installation. If you would like to know more details, go to the Service page.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow rounded border border-secondary" >
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/thinkstockphotos-479282847.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">Desktop Support</h3>
              <p class="card-text">We provide online or in person Desktop Support by helping user solve technical issues. We fix computers, laptops: adding memory (RAM), replacing hard drive, data migration, virus removal, slow computer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="services.html#services">learn more</a>
                <h5 contenteditable="true">60 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow border border-secondary rounded">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/photo-1506399309177-3b43e99fead2.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">System Administration</h3>
              <p class="card-text">We provide Windows Server and Linux Server administration. This includes checking logs. Schedule regular backups. User administration to make sure user have access to network resources.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="services.html#services">learn more</a>
                <h5 style="">100 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow border border-secondary rounded">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/photo-1544197150-b99a580bb7a8.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">Network Installation</h3>
              <p class="card-text">Whether is a small or large project we will be able to assist you. We can assist with installation of network devices like router, switches, firewall, modems, wireless access points, network printers, servers.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="services.html#services">learn more</a>
                <h5>150 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Its working fine at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yd24tpbx/

Comment: well it is not working on the link I posted of the live website

Comment: Then i think its not problem in your code and you should take a look on how you should include Bootstrap in your project

Answer (score 4):

include meta tag your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the columns correctly stack on your live demo when resized to mobile view. If you're still not seeing that on your end, you could add col-12 to your column class list which would cover everything up to the medium break point.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 p-3">
//column content
</div>
```